# Отличие ArrayList от LinkedList?

Tags: java, коллекции

В чем отличие `LinkedList` от `ArrayList`? И в каких случаях на практике удобней использовать `LinkedList`?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

ArrayList - это список на основе массива. 
LinkedList - связанный список на основе элементов и связи между ними.
В качестве LinkedList лучше всего подходит представление вагонов поезда сцепленных последовательно.

**ArrayList** следует использовать, когда в приоритете доступ по индексу, так как эти операции выполняются за константное время. Добавление в конец списка в среднем тоже выполняется за константное время. Кроме того в ArrayList нет дополнительных расходов на хранение связки между элементами. Минусы в скорости вставки/удаления элементов находящихся не в конце списка, так как при этой операции все элементы правее добавляемого/удаляемого сдвигаются.

**LinkedList** удобен когда важнее быстродействие операций вставки/удаления, которые в LinkedList выполняются за константное время. Операции доступа по индексу производятся перебором с начала или конца (смотря что ближе) до нужного элемента. Дополнительные затраты на хранение связки между элементами.

Одним словом - если часто вставляете/удаляете - выбирайте в пользу **LinkedList**, в противном случае **ArrayList**

Comment: "в ArrayList нет дополнительных расходов на хранение связки между элементами", но в нём  выделяется память для дополнительных элементов. И всегда поддерживается массив с большим размером, чем количество элементов в контейнере. Однако при объёмах памяти на устройствах это не критично, как и не критична память расходуемая в  LinkedList-е

Comment: @s_klepcha верно, выделяется. Но во-первых trimToSize() примененный в нужном месте нивелирует эту проблему, а во-вторых каждый элемент LinkedList'а содержит ссылку на текущий объект + 2 соседних и от этих затрат уже никуда не деться. И сколько бы не было доступно памяти при определенных задачах и её может не хватить, а если даже и хватает, то ни к чему использовать более необходимого.

Answer (score 38):

`ArrayList` основан на обычном массиве. Данная коллекция динамически увеличивает размер массива, если в нем не хватает места, при вызове методов `add(T element)`, `addAll(Collection<T> other)` Так же она может его уменьшать, если размер больше количества хранимых элементов, методом `trimToSize()`

`LinkedList` это обычный связанный список, состоящий из узлов. В каждом узле, хранится ссылки на следующий/предыдующий узел и значение. В самом списке, есть ссылки на последний и первый узел, а так же размер.

Чтобы оценить эти структуры данных, можно прибегнуть к ассимптотической сложности выполнения операций:

```
                          |  ArrayList  |  LinkedList 
 add (в начало)           |     O(n)    |   O(1)
 add (в середину)         |     O(n)    |   O(n)
 add (в конец списка)     |     O(n)    |   O(1)
```

В `LinkedList` вставка осуществляется так: находится элемент, за которым должен следовать вставляемый элемент, изменяются ссылки в нем и следующим за ним.

В `ArrayList` создается новый массив, если в текущем нет места. Те элементы которые находятся до вставляемого, остаются на месте, или копируются в новый. Далее добавляется вставляемый элемент. Затем копируются оставщиеся элементы, которые были в исходном.

```
get (первый элемент)        |   O(1)    |   O(1)
get (из середины)           |   O(1)    |   O(n)
get (последний элемент)     |   O(1)    |   O(1)
```

В `LinkedList` чтобы найти элемент с нужным индексом, нужно пройтись поочередно по ссылкам от первого элемента и до последнего (в худшем случае).
В `ArrayList` получения элемента происходит простым взятием по индексу из массива.

```
delete (первый элемент)     |   O(n)    |   O(1)
delete (из середины)        |   O(n)    |   O(n)
delete (последний элемент)  |   O(1)    |   O(1)
```

В `LinkedList` удаление происходит аналогично вставке.
В `ArrayList`, примерно, так же как и при добавлении.

Как мы видем в среднем, сложности одинаковые. Но я бы не стал рекомендовать использовать `LinkedList`, за исключением ситуации когда, преобладает удаление или вставка в начало или конец списка.

`ArrayList` более предсказуем для процессора, с точки зрения расположения данных. Это массив, а там элементы расположены последовательно, занимая непрырывную область памяти. Это хорошо, так как позволяет подгружать данные в кэши процессора без `cache miss'ов`. Процессор не простаивает, ожидая данные из оперативной памяти. С `LinkedList` такого нет, т.к. элементы располагаются в разных участках памяти, и предугадать расположение следующего элемента процессору не под силам.

Код демонстрирующий разницу в производительности:

```
@Fork(1)
@Warmup(iterations = 10)
@Measurement(iterations = 10)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@Threads(1)
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
public class PerformanceTest {
   private static List<Object> arrayList;
   private static List<Object> linkedList;

   private static final int count = 100_000;

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Main.main(args);
   }

   @Setup
   public static void setup() {
      arrayList = new ArrayList<>(count);
      linkedList = new LinkedList<>();

      for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
         arrayList.add(new Object());

      linkedList.addAll(arrayList);
   }

   @Benchmark
   public void removeFromLinkedList(Blackhole blackhole) throws Exception {
      Object object = new Object();
      linkedList.remove(count / 2);
      linkedList.add(count / 2, object);
   }

   @Benchmark
   public void removeFromArrayList(Blackhole blackhole) throws Exception {
      Object object = new Object();
      arrayList.remove(count / 2);
      arrayList.add(count / 2, object);
   }
}
```

На моем компьютере получилось следующее:

```
Benchmark                             Mode  Cnt  Score    Error  Units
PerformanceTest.removeFromArrayList   avgt   10  0.011 ±  0.001  ms/op
PerformanceTest.removeFromLinkedList  avgt   10  0.148 ±  0.001  ms/op
```

Из результатов видно, что `LinkedList` в 14 раз медленнее.

Comment: Сложность добавления в `ArrayList` в конец списка должна быть по идее логарифмическая, а не линейная. Ведь в общем случае список масштабируется в два раза при достижении границ внутреннего массива.

Comment: @GreyGoblin это уже детали реализации

Answer (score 12):

При выборе `ArrayList` в качестве имплементации списка следует понимать что операция добавления элементов может вызвать необходимость увеличения размера массива, что приведет к операции копирования всех элементов из одного массива в другой. В связи с этим следует обращать внимание на первоначальную вместимость, которая может быть указана в конструкторе при создании списка `public ArrayList(int initialCapacity)`.

Если вы не можете оценить предполагаемое кол-во элементов которые будут храниться в коллекции и для вас нет необходимости в доступе к элементам по индексу то лучше обратить внимание на `LinkedList`.

Понимать чем отличаются различные типы коллекций действительно важно, но на практике для большинства прикладных задач, где речь идет о десятках и сотнях элементов, выбор конкретной имплементации коллекции не играет большой роли как в отношении производительности так и в отношении используемой памяти.
Гораздо болле важным моментом является выбор интерфейса коллекции которую вы собираетесь использовать:

- java.util.Collection
- java.util.List
- java.util.Set

**Выбор интерфейса будет влиять непосредственно на логику работы вашего кода.** Интерфейсы также лучше использовать в качестве параметров и возвращаемых типов публичных методов.

Comment: Если создавать instance LinkedList то можно приводить не к интерфейсу List а к Dequeue, при этом изменяются доступные методы.