# удаление каждого К-того элемента из arraylist по кругу

Tags: java, алгоритм

наша задача - для заданного числа человек N и заданного шага K - определить номер счастливчика который останется последним в этой жеребьёвке. Например если всего 10 человек и выбывает каждый 3-й:

N = 10, K = 3
последовательность "вылета" будет такой (в скобках указаны выбывающие номера):

> 1-й круг: 1 2 (3) 4 5 (6) 7 8 (9) 10
>
> 2-й круг:                            1 (2) 4 5 (7) 8 10
>
> 3-й круг:                                                (1) 4 5 (8) 10
>
> 4-й круг:                                                               4 (5) 10
>
> 5-й круг:                                                                        4 (10)

итак победителем оказался тот кто стоял четвертым в начальной позиции.

Входные данные содержат количество человек N и размер шага K.
Ответ должен содержать "выигрышный номер" (считая с 1).

Имеется вопрос насчёт того, как после окончания первого круга во втором круге начать удаление не со второго элемента, а с первого уже

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList <Integer> list1 = new ArrayList();
        int n = 88;
        int sh = 6;
        for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
            list1.add(i+1);
        }

        while (list1.size()!=1) {
            for (int i = sh-1; i<list1.size(); i++){
                list1.remove(i);
            }

        }
        System.out.print(list1.get(0));


    }
}
```

Дошёл до этого кода, но в итоге в while оказался вечный цикл, хотя не могу понять почему

Comment: А вы не удаляйте ненужные, а собирайте новый лист из оставшихся. Удалять значения в итерируемом объекте - верный способ обеспечить себе проблемы на пустом месте. (тут рекурсия в тему будет кстати)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это [двухтысячелетняя задача Иосифа Флавия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%98%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B0_%D0%A4%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F) в современной формулировке: идём ко кругу, убиваем каждого `K`-ого, последний выживает. Вопрос на какую позицию в круге от начала отсчёта встать, чтобы выжить, если всего `N` людей.

#### Линейное решение — O(n)

Есть простой линейный (`O(n)`)алгоритм на основе [рекуррентного соотношения](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem#The_general_case):

```
g(1, k) = 0
g(n, k) = (g(n-1, k) + k) % n
```

где `g(n, k)` это индекс безопасного места в массиве (`0 <= g(n, k) < n`). Для примера в вопросе (отсчёт от единицы):

```
public class Josephus {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
      System.out.println(safe_position(10, 3));
  }
  public static int safe_position(int n, int k) {
      int g = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
          g = (g + k) % (i + 1);
      return g + 1;
  }
}
```

Реализация транслирована на Java [из решения на Питоне](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Josephus_problem#Python).

#### O(k log n)

Для маленьких `k` и больших `n` можно использовать [`O(k log n)` решение](http://geofhagopian.net/images/Josephus.htm):

```
public class JosephusLog {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        System.out.println(safe_position_log(2147483647, 3));
    }
    public static int safe_position_log(int n, int k) {
        double x = k * (double) n;
        while(x > n) {
            x = (long)((k * (x - n) - 1) / (k - 1));
        }
        return (int)x;
    }
}
```

#### Замкнутая формула — O(1)

Могут существовать и замкнутые формулы (O(1) решение для n,k размером с машинное слово). К примеру, [для k=2](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%98%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B0_%D0%A4%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.97.D0.B0.D0.BC.D0.BA.D0.BD.D1.83.D1.82.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D1.84.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.BC.D1.83.D0.BB.D0.B0) (достаточно [старший бит в конец записать](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uCsD3ZGzMgE&feature=youtu.be&t=11m58s)). Вот реализация на Java O(1) решения для `k=3` (за постоянное время, не зависящее от `n`), из статьи [The Josephus Problem by Lorenz Halbeisen](http://user.math.uzh.ch/halbeisen/publications/pdf/jos.pdf):

```
public class Josephus3 {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        System.out.println(safe_position3(10));
    }
    public static int safe_position3(int n) {
        // j(n, k, n-l) = (n - c_m) * k + d_m;
        // return j(n, 3, n) + 1;
        switch(n) {
        case 1:
        case 4:
            return 1;
        case 2:
        case 3:
            return 2;
        default:
            assert(n >= 5);
            int k = 3;
            double alpha = 0.8111352513650005; // theorem 2 [jos] k = 3; l = 0;
            double q = k / (double)(k-1);
            long m = Math.round(Math.log(n / alpha) / Math.log(q)); // n >= 5
            double e_m = alpha * Math.pow(q, m);
            long c_m = Math.round(e_m);
            if (c_m > n) {
                m -= 1;
                e_m /= q;
                c_m = Math.round(e_m);
            }
            assert(c_m <= n);  // c_m <= n < c_m_plus_1
            int d_m = (e_m - c_m) < 0 ? 1 : 0;
            return (int)((n - c_m) * k + d_m + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Решение работает для всех `int n` от `1` до `2147483647`.

Answer (score 5):

```
package com.company;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList <Integer> list1 = new ArrayList();
        int n = 10;
        int k = 3;
        for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
            list1.add(i+1);
        }
        int pos =0;
        while (list1.size()!=1)
        {
            pos = (pos+k-1)%list1.size();
            list1.remove(pos);
        }
        System.out.print(list1.get(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: это работает, но это квадратичный алгоритм *O(n²)* (при увеличении n в 10 раз, время исполнения в 100 раз увеличивается). Есть [простое линейное решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/716533/23044)

Comment: Ну а какая мне разница? Я знал о другом решении, но автор попросил "починить" его решение

Comment: ваш ответ даёт решение для вопроса в заголовке (поэтому я ему +1 поставил). В целом, ответ следует писать не только лично для автора (Stack Overflow это не help-desk), а так чтобы он мог бы быть полезен и будущим читателям, пришедших из поисковика, привлечённые формулировкой более общей задачи в вопросе. Мой комментарий, который явно упоминает временную сложность, именно для этих читателей, да и самому автору линейное решение может быть интересным. [Какими должны быть критерии оценки качества базы знаний?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4181/23044)

Comment: Кстати, где вы тут n^2 увидели?

Comment: если это не ясно, задайте отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Ну тут один цикл while, который за каждую итерацию "убирает" по одному элементу, где здесь квадрат?

Comment: @9Pasha https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/568119#583973

Comment: [Почему ArrayList.remove(i) в цикле ведёт к квадратичному времени выполнения?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/722253/23044)