# Почему ArrayList.remove(i) в цикле ведёт к квадратичному времени выполнения?

Tags: java, алгоритм, language-lawyer

На вопрос [удаление каждого К-того элемента из arraylist по кругу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/716454/23044) был [предложен ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/716490/23044):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList <Integer> list1 = new ArrayList();
        int n = 10;
        int k = 3;
        for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
            list1.add(i+1);
        }
        int pos =0;
        while (list1.size()!=1)
        {
            pos = (pos+k-1)%list1.size();
            list1.remove(pos);
        }
        System.out.print(list1.get(0));
    }
}
```

Это квадратичный алгоритм *O(n²)*, но по-видимому это не очевидно, так как приводит к вопросам:

... [где вы тут n^2 увидели?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/716454/%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%9a-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-arraylist-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d1%83/716490#comment1077470_716490) ... [тут один цикл while, который за каждую итерацию "убирает" по одному элементу, где здесь квадрат?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/716454/%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%9a-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-arraylist-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d1%83/716490#comment1077475_716490)

Как себя ведут популярные реализации Java? Гарантирует ли спецификация языка *O(n)* поведение для `ArrayList.remove(i)` для произвольного индекса?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/568119#583973

Comment: @Nofate: ваше ссылка обратное говорит (что гарантируется O(n)). Она подтверждает, что `ArrayList.remove(i)` это  O(n) операция, что для данного алгоритма ведёт к O(n²) : `n` раз удаляется по одному элементу (`n*n`). Осталось только ссылку на спецификацию языка найти, где явно О(n) для ArrayList.remove() гарантируется

Comment: Да, я как-то не так вопрос прочитал )

Comment: @jfs ссылка от zRrr и есть спецификация API. Спецификация языка (JVMLS) больше про синтаксис, стандартная библиотека в нее не входит.

Comment: @Nofate: конкретную цитату пожалуйста, где хоть что-то сказано о гарантиях временной сложности. Очевидно, что я могу в гугл вставить одно слово ArrayList, чтобы ссылку на документацию найти.

Comment: @jfs *The size, isEmpty, get, set, iterator, and listIterator operations run in constant time. The add operation runs in amortized constant time, that is, adding n elements requires O(n) time. **All of the other operations run in linear time (roughly speaking).***

Comment: @jfs если найдете что-то более формальное, чем абзац из javadoc – welcome.

Comment: @Nofate: этого вполне достаточно (если практические реализации следует этой документации). Можно в виде ответа опубликовать. Подсказка со стороны zRrr выше моей головы пролетела. Я смотрел документацию методов, но не догадался введение прочитать или поискать буквально слова "roughly speaking"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из Java API Specification по поводу [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

- Операции `size`, `isEmpty`, `get`, `set`, `iterator` и `listIterator` выполняются за константное время. Операция `add` выполняется за амортизированное время *O(1)*, то есть *n* элементов будут добавлены за *O(n)*. Все прочие операции выполняются за линейное время (грубо говоря).

> The `size`, `isEmpty`, `get`, `set`, `iterator`, and `listIterator` operations run in constant time. The `add` operation runs in amortized constant time, that is, adding *n* elements requires *O(n)* time. All of the other operations run in linear time (roughly speaking).

`ArrayList.remove()` относится к категории "прочие операции", поэтому удаление одного произвольного элемента это *O(n)* операция. Цикл из вопроса по одному удаляет элементы (всего *n* удалений). Итого: *n * O(n) = O(n * n)* то есть представленный в вопросе алгоритм является квадратичным.

Comment: Чтобы цитата ответом стала, стоит явно упомянуть как она влияет на временную сложность алгоритма из вопроса: ArrayList.remove() относится к категории "прочие операции", поэтому удвоение одного произвольного элемента это O(n) операция. Цикл из вопроса по одному удаляет элементы (всего n удалений). Итого: `n * O(n) = O(n*n)` то есть представленный в вопросе алгоритм является квадратичным.

Comment: @jfs как скажете )

Comment: На самом деле, тут не совсем `n * O(n)`, т. к. на первом шаге элементов `n`, на втором `n - 1`, ..., на последнем 1. Поэтому общее к-во операций не превосходит `C * (n + (n - 1) + ... + 1) = C * n * (n + 1)/2`, что всё-таки равно `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @VladD: на всякий случай: `O(n * n)` и `O(n ^ 2)` это одно и то же 
(чтобы разночтений не было) . `O(n*n) == O(n*n/2) == O(C * n * n)`, где `C` это константа, независящая от `n`.  Какой бы константой  `C` не была -- квадратичность алгоритма это не изменяет.

Comment: @jfs: Я в курсе. Я ведь и написал в конце комментария: _что всё-таки **равно** `O(n^2)`_.

Comment: @jfs: «Всё-таки» не в смысле «в отличие от вашего ответа...», а «тем не менее, несмотря на другой ход вычислений, приводит к тому же...»

Answer (score 1):

Хороший вопрос, сейчас объясню, в чем здесь дело.
Дело в том, что реализация коллекции `ArrayList` основана на массиве. А как известно, под массив память выделяется блоками, таким образом доступ к элементу осуществляется за константное время - просто по его индексу. И можно было бы на этом закончить, если бы не одно НО.
При удалении элемента из `ArrayList` происходит *сдвиг* всех элементов после идекса удяляемого элемента в массиве на одну позицию левее.
Сейчас поясню на примере. Исходный массив:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Мы делаем `.remove(3)` и получаем такое состояние:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 6]
```

После чего последний индекс массива (последняя цифра 6) зануляется.
Сдвиг осуществляется посредством нативного метода `System.arrayCopy()`, который написан не на Java и работает **в разы** быстрее обычного ручного поэлементного копирования, тем не менее скорость его работы в нотации Big O оценивается близкой к O(n).

Для случая с `LinkedList`, который основан на двусвязном списке, хоть мы и удаляем по индексу, в любом случае нам необходимо найти этот элемент прежде, чем удалить, а это обычный поиск линейной сложности O(n)