# Работа со списком в цикле while

Tags: python, список, списки

Задачка с CodeAbbey. Смысл задачи по ссылке, если кому интересно:
[Josephus Problem](http://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/josephus-problem--ru).
Мой код:

```
n = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
m = list(range(1, n[0]+1))
m_ = []
k = n[1]
a1 = k-1
while len(m)>1:
    for i in range(a1, len(m), k):
        m_.append(m[i])
    s = m.index(m_[-1])
    a1 = k - len(m) + s
    for j in range(len(m_)):
        m.remove(m_[j])
    m_.clear()
print(m[0])
```

Выдает ошибку:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):  
> File "solution.py", line 9, in <module>    
> s = m.index(m_[-1])IndexError: list index out of range
> ```

Т.е. получается, что список `m_` пустой, или другими словами после первой итерации выполняется команда `m_.clear()`, и повторного заполнения списка на цикле `for` не происходит. Перепробовал различные варианты очищения списка: через `del m_[:]`, циклом `for` через метод `m_.pop()` - проблема ожидаемо не тут.

Comment: Для меня ваша программа для ввода `10 3` работает правильно (результат `4`). Какой ваш ввод выдал ошибку?

Comment: Любой из предлагаемых в поле ввода на сайте. Например, 97 8.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [удаление каждого К-того элемента из arraylist по кругу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/716454/23044)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема для ввода `97 8` здесь:

После многих итераций цикла `while` возникнет такое состояние переменных:

```
# n  = [97, 8]        
# a1 = 7
# k  = 8
# m  = [13, 52, 73, 87]
# m_ = []
```

Это значит, что в следующей итерации цикла `while` его первый `for` цикл

```
for i in range(a1, len(m), k):
    m_.append(m[i])
```

будет (после замещения значений) выглядеть вот так:

```
for i in range(7, 4, 8):
    m_.append(m[i])
```

Это значит, что его команда `m_.append(m[i])` не совершится *ни один раз*, и так список `m_` остается пустым.

(Следующая строка

```
s = m.index(m_[-1])
```

по этому выдает вашу ошибку.)