# Сравнение ArrayList и LinkedList

Tags: java, коллекции, arraylist, linked-list

Решил сравнить быстродействие. Написал простой пример:

```
public class ServiceList {
    public void addList(List list, String name){
        Date start = new Date();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4000000; i++) {
            list.add(new String());
        }
        Date finish = new Date();


        long time = finish.getTime() - start.getTime();
        //sum = sum + time;

        System.out.println("ADD "+ name + " : " + time);
    }
}


public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                new ServiceList().addList(new ArrayList(), "ArrayList");
                new ServiceList().addList(new LinkedList(), "LinkedList"); 
                System.out.println("- - - - - - - - -");

            }
        }
    }
```

Результаты просто удивляют:

```
ADD ArrayList : 1218
ADD LinkedList : 2673
- - - - - - - - -
ADD ArrayList : 156
ADD LinkedList : 187
- - - - - - - - -
ADD ArrayList : 141
ADD LinkedList : 125
- - - - - - - - -
ADD ArrayList : 141
ADD LinkedList : 297
- - - - - - - - -
ADD ArrayList : 31
ADD LinkedList : 656
- - - - - - - - -
ADD ArrayList : 188
ADD LinkedList : 32
- - - - - - - - -
ADD ArrayList : 223
ADD LinkedList : 422
- - - - - - - - -
ADD ArrayList : 31
ADD LinkedList : 1001
- - - - - - - - -
ADD ArrayList : 312
ADD LinkedList : 391
- - - - - - - - -
ADD ArrayList : 31
ADD LinkedList : 1141
- - - - - - - - -
```

Почему они такие разные? А порой даже linked быстрее?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отличие ArrayList от LinkedList?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/568119/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-arraylist-%d0%be%d1%82-linkedlist)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно писать микро-тесты в Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/824247/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2-java)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Нет смысла сравнивать эти структуры, если нет контекста их применения. Вставки только в конец? Удаления будут? Доступ нужен к каким элементам?

1. У вас вставка всегда в конец. Там сложность `O(1)` для обеих реализаций. Вот только у `ArrayList` ресайз происходит, если он полностью забит. А стартовый размер, если память не изменяет, равен `10`. То есть, уже после десятой вставки там будет ресайз.
2. По поводу вставки. `LinkedList` выигрывает, когда вставки осуществляются в середину списка. Особенно, если вы переиспользуете итератор, тогда вставка/удаление может выполняться за `O(1)`.
3. Обращение к элементу в `ArrayList` всегда за `O(1)`. В `LinkedList` в худшем случае `O(n)`.
4. Мне почему-то кажется, что вы там больше замеряете не работу с коллекциями, а время на создание строк. А если там в промежутках stop the world у GC будет, то вообще не релевантный тест тогда.
5. У вас тесты без прогрева. По-хорошему, до тестов нужно прогреть jvm.
6. Использовать `Date` для замеров времени - ужас. Используйте `System.nanoTime()` или хотя бы `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

К чему это я? Ну да, вы получили какие-то метрики, но на них не сделать никаких выводов, пока не ясен контекст использования этих структур.

Comment: Хочу полностью сравнить. Добавление, вставку, удаление и поиск  в начале, середине и конце, но пока только на добавлении остановился. Как по хорошему сделать метрику более менее и прогреть jvm?

Comment: @KeyJibo по поводу тестов я небольшую памятку написал https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/824248/15479