# Как правильно писать микро-тесты в Java?

Tags: java, производительность, jvm, java-faq

Как лучше писать микро-тесты/тесты на производительность в Java? Какие основные пункты, на которые стоит обратить внимание?

Comment: А что такое микро-тесты? Это не юнит-тесты?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Юнит-тест проверяет, как правило, что программа ведёт себя как надо, типо `Asserts.Equal(2 + 2, 4)`, а бенчи перформанс оценивают.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/1991579

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Ключевые моменты:

**Правило 0:** правильно сформулируйте задачу и что именно вы хотите проверить.

Плохо поставленная задача:

> Я хочу проверить, что быстрее: `ArrayList` или `LinkedList`?

Лучше:

> В моём приложении вставка чаще всего происходит в середину списка. Что для моей задачи будет лучше: `ArrayList` или `LinkedList`?

Ещё лучше:

> В моём приложении вставка чаще всего происходит в середину списка, а при чтении мне нужно, как правило, за раз просматривать несколько элементов подряд. Что для моей задачи будет лучше: `ArrayList` или `LinkedList`?

**Правило 1:** почитайте авторитетные статьи про различные JVM и микро-бенчмарки. Например, [Brian Goetz, 2005](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp02225). Но не ожидайте чудес от замеров. Все бенчмарки замеряют ограниченный набор метрик в рамках контекста.

**Правило 2:** всегда включайте фазу прогрева jvm, прогоняющую ваши тесты для полной инициализации и компиляции перед фазой самих замеров. (По-хорошему, нужно провести несколько десятков тысяч итераций).

**Правило 3:** Запускайте всегда с флагами `-XX:+PrintCompilation`, `-verbose:gc` и т.п., чтобы быть уверенными, что компилятор и другие части jvm не будут выполнять незапланированных операций во время фазы замеров.

**Правило 4:** имейте в виду разницу между -client и -server, а также OSR (On Stack Replacement) и регулярной компиляцией. Предпочитайте сервер клиенту и регулярную компиляцию вместо OSR.

**Правило 5:** помните об эффекте инициализации. Не выводите ничего в консоль впервые в фазе замеров, так как вывод инициализирует классы. Не загружайте новый классы вне фазы прогрева, если, конечно, вы не тестируете саму загрузку классов.

**Правило 6:** помните об эффектах деоптимизации и перекомпиляции. Не допускайте, чтобы какие-то ветки коды впервые использовались во время фазы замеров, потому что компилятор может перекомпилировать код на основе более раннего оптимистического предположения о том, что этот путь не будет использоваться вообще. **Правило 2** - это ваша первая линия защиты от таких эффектов.

**Правило 7:** используйте соответствующие инструменты, чтобы читать кишки компилятора, и ожидайте, что будете удивлены от произведённого кода. Осмотрите код самостоятельно, прежде чем формировать теории о том, что же замедляет его.

**Правило 8:** уменьшите шум в ваших измерениях. Запустите свой тест на машине в спокойном состоянии. Запустите его несколько раз, отбросив выбросы. Используйте `-Xbatch` для сериализации компилятора с приложением и рассмотрите возможность установки `-XX:CICompilerCount=1` для предотвращения параллельной работы компилятора с самим собой.

**Правило 9:** используйте уже готовые библиотеки для замеров. Например: [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/), [Caliper](https://github.com/google/caliper) или [Bill and Paul's Excellent UCSD Benchmarks for Java](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/users/wgg/JavaProf/javaprof.html).

**Правило 10:** если пишите, всё же, сами, то используйте `System.nanoTime()`, т.к. с `System.currentTimeMillis()` могут быть проблемы. На Linux системах при использовании NTP демона разность двух последовательных `System.currentTimeMillis()` может быть отрицательной. Или можно воспользоваться `StopWatch` классами из тех же [Apache commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/StopWatch.html) или [Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html).

**Правило 11:** будет полезно вызывать `System.gc()` между тестами (**но не между итерациями!**).

## Полезные статьи:

1. [Dynamic compilation and performance measurement](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp12214/) от IBM.
2. [5 things you didn't know about Java performance monitoring](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-5things8/index.html) от IBM.
3. [Avoiding Benchmarking Pitfalls on the JVM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-benchmarking-2266277.html).