# Измерение времени отработки метода для Android

Tags: java, android

Какие наилучшие способы измерения времени отработки метода, которые можно использовать в приложении для Android? Мне приходят на приходит на ум только два способа:

1) использовать просто `System.nanoTime()`:

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
// выполнение метода
end elapsedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
```

2) использовать AspectJ

Но по поводу обоих вышеприведённых способов у меня есть сомнения. По поводу первого способа: будет ли это измерение времени точным? И по поводу второго: не будет ли привносить много побочных эффектов типа увеличения времени компиляции и времени работы программы? Есть ли какое-либо лучшее решение?

Comment: Если ручками хотите, то `System.nanoTime()`. Если по-нормальному, то JMH, Caliper или Bill and Paul's Excellent UCSD Benchmarks for Java. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/824248/15479

Answer (score 4):

Мне в свое время помог TimingLogger.

Из документации :

```
TimingLogger timings = new TimingLogger(YOUR_TAG, "methodA");
 // ... do some work A ...
timings.addSplit("work A");
// ... do some work B ... 
timings.addSplit("work B");
// ... do some work C ... 
timings.addSplit("work C");
timings.dumpToLog();
```

и вывод должен быть такой:

```
 D/TAG     ( 3459): methodA: begin
 D/TAG     ( 3459): methodA:      9 ms, work A
 D/TAG     ( 3459): methodA:      1 ms, work B
 D/TAG     ( 3459): methodA:      6 ms, work C
 D/TAG     ( 3459): methodA: end, 16 ms
```

Не забудте включить свой тэг в логах : 
adb shell setprop log.tag.YOUR_TAG VERBOSE

PS: ссылка на origin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23913762/best-method-to-measure-execution-time-in-android