# Правильное измерение скорости выполнения кода

Tags: java

Правильно ли измерять скорость выполнения кода таким образом, какие плюсы и минусы такого подхода

```
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    doSomething();
    System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + result);
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно писать микро-тесты в Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/824247/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2-java)

Comment: @Suvitruf а почему именно микро?)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ потому что чекают время исполнения :D

Comment: @Suvitruf а вдруг он там в файл или в сокет пишет?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Suvitruf вот и я про то же, нельзя дать однозначный ответ, на этот вопрос, всегда tradeoff

Comment: @StrangerintheQ эм, тогда его тем более нужно закрыть)

Comment: @Suvitruf не считаю так, т.к. он заставляет подумать

Comment: @Suvitruf тем более многие вопросы именно ответами хороши, он "отражает стремление разобраться", человек спрашивает про плюсы и минусы в конце концов

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот код, в котором есть прогрев, для замера используются наносекунды а не микросекунды(так точнее), а также сам код выполняется 1000 раз, а потом находится среднее время выполнения:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getTime());
}

private static void testMethod() {
    //Код, время выполнения которого нужно узнать
}

/**
 * Метод для измерения времени выполнения метода testMethod
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/2404378/7150209
 */
private static double getTime() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i ++) { //прогрев JVM
        testMethod();
    }
    int count = 1000; //первоначальное кол-во повтора выполнения testMethod

    while(true) {
        long begin =  System.nanoTime();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i ++)
            testMethod();

        long end = System.nanoTime();

        if ((end - begin) < 1000000000) { //Прогон тестов пока суммарное выполнения count раз
            count *= 100000;              //testMethod`a не будет равно несколько секунд
            continue;
        }

        return (double)(end - begin) / count;
    }
}
```

Тест может выполнятся достаточно долгое время. 
Вообще для замера рекомендуется [использовать библиотеку JMH](https://habr.com/ru/post/349914/).

Answer (score 6):

Неправильно. Если метод `doSomething` хорошо оптимизируется JIT-компилятором, измерения без прогрева этого не учтут. Если в процессе выполнения `doSomething` сработает сборщик мусора, время его работы приплюсуется к времени работы метода. Правильно измерить *управляемый код* - это целое искусство. Полезно послушать на эту тему [этот](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mw0Vimj39cI) и [этот](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8pMfUopQ9Es) доклады. А измерения лучше доверить  специально разработанному фреймворку - [JMH](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/).

Answer (score 2):

Нельзя дать однозначный ответ правильно или не правильно.
Можно лишь сказать насколько точный будет замер, а от этого уже решать подходит это Вам в Вашей ситуации или нет.

Замерить продолжительность операции таким образом можно, но в общем случае результаты будут сильно отличаться от действительности по множеству причин, так же вы можете наблюдать разные результаты в от замера к замеру.

Однако если операция достаточно продолжительная и результаты вас устроят не особо точные - таким способом воспользоваться можно.

Например в движке компьютерной игры, я пользуюсь именно таким методом проверки некоторых задержек.

Как уже успел ответить @Sergey Gornostaev для более-менее точных замеров существуют специальные средства и это целое искусство.