# Связный, двусвязный, двунаправленный связный список

Tags: java, linked-list

Читал в одной статье, что есть такие виды связной, двусвязной и двунаправленный 
 связный список.
Хотел бы спросить, в `Java`, `LinkedList` - это какой список? И чем они отличаются?

Comment: Первые ссылки в поисковиках по запросу "Java linkedlist" https://habr.com/ru/post/127864/
Чем отличаются - гуглятся по запросу "Отличия одно и двух направленных списков" собственно направленный\связанный - синонимы в данном случае.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Отличие ArrayList от LinkedList?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/568119/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-arraylist-%d0%be%d1%82-linkedlist)

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку прошло время, а ответа нет - оставлю свой.
Ссылка на статью также не была предоставлена, поэтому отвечаю как понял.

1. "Связной" список, или другими словами односвязный - список, где каждый элемент ссылается только на один следующий. У последнего нет ссылки.
2. "Двусвязной" или двусвязный - список, где каждый элемент ссылается на следующий и предыдущий. Первый и последний cоотвественно не имеют ссылок на предыдущий и следующий.
3. "Двойной двусвязной список" - каша масляная, поскольку в списках связь задаёт направление. Другими словами это то же самое что и двусвязный список. Односвязный - однонаправленный, двусвязный - двунаправленный.
   По сути взято [отсюда](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA).

Теперь про LinkedList. Он реализует сразу три интерфейса List, Queue, Dequeue. То есть это структура которая хранит порядок элементов, поддерживает добавление элементов с обеих концов и позволяет себя обходить с обеих направлений. Или в терминологии вопроса - двусвязный (двунаправленный) список.

Answer (score 1):

Связный (он же односвязный список), в терминах Java, элемент списка реализуется приблизительно так (в старые добрые времена, когда не была коллекций делали это так):

```
class Entry<T> {
    T data; //собственно сам контент
    Entry<T> next; //ссылка на следующий элемент
}
```

Элемент двусвязного списка так:

```
class Entry<T> {
    T data; //собственно сам контент
    Entry<T> prev; //ссылка на предыдущий элемент
    Entry<T> next; //ссылка на следующий элемент
}
```

В Java Collection нет чистой реализации односвязного списка, реализован двусвязный список в виде `LinkedList`

Comment: А вот и есть - ConcurrentLinkedQueue. "This class is a member of the Java Collections Framework." - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html